# Diff between various CPU masks - Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I was going through the boot up  code and came across the following masks . The ones set in boot_cpu_init()

```
CPU online mask : The number of CPU's available for getting scheduled on
CPU active mask : The number of CPU's on which some task can be migrated to (not very clear as to the difference between online and active) 
CPU present mask : Total number of CPU's limited by max cpu's variable
CPU possible mask : Total number of possible CPU's in the system
```

But its still not clear to me why these masks are present . Why not just have cpu_online_bits() alone . Wouldn't that suffice to see which CPU is available and total CPU's that are available to the system ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same questions and found your post here. After digging into it, I got some points about them. CPU hotplug plays an important part in them.

The 'possible' mask and 'present' mask stand for static CPU resources, as well as 'online' and 'active' mean dynamic ones. The static resources are declared either at compile time or at the booting stage. It won't be changed during kernel life time. The dynamic resources will vary with CPU hotplug operations.

Sometimes you may need to allocate or initialize some other resources for each 'possible' CPUs, like to initialize lists for each 'possible' CPUs in blk_softirq_init().

It's harder to tell the differences between CPU 'online' and 'active' from booting time, however we can get the idea during the procedure to offline a CPU. The steps to put CPU down look like the following graph
http://image.slidesharecdn.com/cpuhotplugrcuandbig-140320112138-phpapp02/95/lce12-cpu-hotplug-rcu-and-biglittle-22-638.jpg?cb=1395333911

When CPU entered 1st step, i.e. the CPU_DOWN_PREPARE, the scheduler marks it as not 'active', but it's still 'online' at the moment. Scheduler could not migrate any task to it at this time. After the CPU is totally removed, it's not 'online' anymore.

I am not sure whether you still need the information or not, but write down some more detail traces in 
http://vh21.github.io/linux/2015/04/28/linux-cpu-mask.html